# Telerik Kendo ui treeView - expand/collapse node on single click

Tags: kendo-ui, treeview

I am new to Telerik Kendo UI and currently working on a `TreeView` (http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/treeview/index)

Basically it expands/collapses when I double click on it or when I click on triangle icon. My question is this: how can I change this behaviour to expand/collapse the tree node on a single click?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do it using jQuery. Here is a code assuming that kendoTreeView id is "treeview":

```
$("#treeview").on('click', '.k-in', function () {
    var tree = $("#treeview").data('kendoTreeView');
    var item = $(this).closest('.k-item');
    if (item.attr('aria-expanded') === "true") {
        tree.collapse(item);
    }
    else {
        tree.expand(item);
    }
});
```

Or even shorter:

```
$("#treeview").on("click", ".k-in", function (e) {
    var tree = $("#treeview").data('kendoTreeView');
    tree.toggle($(e.target).closest(".k-item"));
});
```

Working example: http://dojo.telerik.com/ESofU